# Deffered computed does not see last entered symbol in input field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, knockout.js

I have one problem in my autotests (selenium).

Where are one input field in web form:

```
<input data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></input>
```

And model to this field:

```
this.searchText = ko.observable('');
this.invert = ko.observable(false);
this.defferedSearchFilter = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return {
        text: this.searchText(),
        invert: this.invert()
    }
}, this).extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: params.throttleInterval || 500, method: 'notifyWhenChangesStop' } });
```

By value in the `defferedSearchFilter` variable, the list is filtered. Autotest checks this filter by algorithm:

1. Enter value %95% in input field
2. Wait for filtration
3. Checks items in list by clicking on items, because some information hided into item.

But sometimes (chance <1%) computed field fires twice, because it does not see last entered symbol. For example I collect logs from selenium and chrome (screenshots confirm their):

Selenium:
[2017-07-17 15:41:31,224] (DEBUG) Fill By.CssSelector: .col3 .entityContent #linkListFastSearch_0, value to input: ***%95%*** - success

In this moment selenium creates screenshoot. Value in input - ***%95%***

Chrome:
[5624:5680:0717/154131.625:INFO:CONSOLE(42)] "FastSearch id = 4 changed. New text = "***%95***"", source: http://localhost/WebUI/Scripts/uicontrols/basic/fastsearch.js (42)

After filtration selenium clicks on item. Selenuim:
[2017-07-17 15:41:34,686] (DEBUG) Click By.CssSelector: [id='linkTargetCode_95']  - success

And after throttle interval computed field is change to correct value. Chrome:
[5624:5680:0717/154134.802:INFO:CONSOLE(42)] "FastSearch id = 4 changed. New text = "***%95%***"", source: http://localhost/WebUI/Scripts/uicontrols/basic/fastsearch.js (42)

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using textInput, The textInput binding links a text box () or text area () with a viewmodel property, providing two-way updates between the viewmodel property and the element’s value.

Unlike the value binding, textInput provides instant updates from the DOM for all types of user input, including autocomplete, drag-and-drop, and clipboard events.

```
<input data-bind="textInput: searchText" />
```

Browsers are highly inconsistent in the events that fire in response to unusual text entry mechanisms such as cutting, dragging, or accepting autocomplete suggestions. The value binding, even with extra options such as valueUpdate: afterkeydown to get updates on particular events, does not cover all text entry scenarios on all browsers.

The textInput binding is specifically designed to handle a wide range of browser quirks, to provide consistent and immediate model updates even in response to unusual text entry methods.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html

Comment: Great! It's work fine for me. Thanks you very match!